# Is the number of result sets limited in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is the number of result sets limited that a stored procedure can return in SQL Server? Or is there any other component between server and a .Net Client using sqlncli11 limiting it? I'm thinking of really large numbers like 100000 result sets.

I couldn't find a specific answer to this in the Microsoft docs or here on SO.

My use case:
A stored procedure that iterates over a cursor and produces around 100 rows each iteration. I *could* collect all the rows in a temp table first, but since this is a long-running operation I want the client to start sooner with processing the results. Also the temp table can get quite large and the execution plans shows 98% cost on the INSERT INTO part.

Comment: There's no limit, no, but if you *Are* returning 100,000's of result sets in a single batch, I would suggest you have a (major) design flaw. I'd go as far to say that if you're producing 10's of result sets you probably do as well, unless they're not *really* meant for consumption (such as if you have a large migration script that outputs some information into data sets). This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you using a `CURSOR` in the first place, and why only 100 rows when a well design database can handle 100,000's of rows trivially.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking of really large numbers like 100000 result sets.

Ah, I hope you have a LOT of time.

100k result sets means 100k SELECT statements.

Just switching from one result set to the next will take - together - a long time. 1ms? that is 100 seconds.

> Is the number of result sets limited that a stored procedure can return in SQL Server?

Not to my knowledge. Remember, those are not part of any real metadata - there is a stream of data, endmarker, next stream. The number of resultsets a procedure returns is not defined (as: it can vary).

> Also the temp table can get quite large

I have seen temp tables with hundreds of GB.

> and the execution plans shows 98% cost on the INSERT INTO part.

That basically indicates that there is otherwise not a lot happening. Note that unless you do optimization - the relative cost is not relevant, the absolute is.

Have you considered a middle ground? Collect data and return resultsets grouping i.e. 100 resultsets.

But yes, staging into temp has a lot of overhead. It also means you can not start returning data BEFORE all processing is finished. That can be a bummer. Your approach will allow processing to start while the SP is still working on more data.

Comment: It's a large complex export easily running an hour or more. That is expected and accepted. But I'd rather have the client start writing data out to file immediately instead of waiting for an hour and then getting a heap of data at once. - But the idea of buffering the data in a #temp table and writing it out every couple of iterations is good. Doesn't eliminate the INSERT cost but should reduce the result sets to something "reasonable".